# need to re-write a specific link with mod-rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

/support-category/?category=**category name**

to:

/support/category/**category name**

This does not appear to be working:

```
RewriteRule ^support/category/$4 support-category/?category=$4 [nc]
```

Thank you :)

Also if I am getting the category name with a get request will that work when the link is accessed via the /support/category/category name format?

here's the entire .hatacces folder and it is located in the root directory of the site.

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/var/www/vhosts/xxx.de/dev.xxx.de/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user

# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC CDN
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC CDN
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^support/category/([^/]+)$ support-category/?category=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

added this to functions.php

```
function rewrite_support() {
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    add_rewrite_rule('^support/category/([^/]+)/?$','support-category/?category=$matches[1]','top');
}

add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_support');
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^support/category/([^/]+)$ support-category/?category=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: this doesn't appear to work. Does it take a while to propagate or something? @anubhava

Comment: What is the full URL did you enter in browser? Are there more rules in this .htaccess and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: Ah so `/support-category/?category=category name` is Wordpress page/post?

Comment: Hmm you should have told it earlier. In that case internal rewrite won't work and you will need to use WP API for rewrite.

Comment: is there any way to do a custom rewrite in wordpress?

Comment: Yes as I said you need to use WP API for rewrite.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule what file do i edit to add the new rewrite rule?

Comment: Yes that's the one I was talking about.

Comment: do i need to update the template file in question? or is there a specific file where i add that rewrite rule?

Comment: This goes in your theme's function.php file and then add hooks. I believe you can find many examples of that in WP docs.

Comment: function rewrite_support() {
 $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
 add_rewrite_rule('^support/category/([^/]+)/?$','support-category/?category=$matches[1]','top');
}

add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_support'); this is the code i added and it still does not appear to work correctly...

Comment: added the info to the original question

Comment: Sorry I can only help with rewrite stuff, don't know much about WP APIs